# Why is the threadpool for core.async in clojure created with fixed thread pool of # of cores times 2 plus 42?

Tags: clojure, core.async

The threadpool [implementation](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async/impl/exec/threadpool.clj) in core.async clojure library uses a FixedThreadPoolExecutor of size = # of cores * 2 + 42.

```clj
(defonce the-executor
  (Executors/newFixedThreadPool
    (-> (Runtime/getRuntime)
        (.availableProcessors)
        (* 2)
        (+ 42))
    (conc/counted-thread-factory "async-dispatch-%d" true)))
```

Is there a reason to use these numbers (# of cores times 2 plus 42) in particular? Is this optimal for all devices? I just want to know how did rich hickey (and contributors) settled with these numbers.

---

Thank you nullptr.

Here is the discussion for those who are interested:
http://clojure-log.n01se.net/date/2013-08-29.html#15:45a

Comment: That algorithm was introduced [here](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/commit/7b64bd8a22c2b6df69c23dce34eb66d705f5bf1a).  You might try asking the [author](https://github.com/halgari).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some discussion at the link below, but it's basically arbitrary.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/mT-r3EDeC74/dvaFqHnAZxgJ